# Need help, my code has an error i cant find

Tags: python-2.7

So I started using python and I'm building a calculator...
except it skips some of my code. I think its an error I made but I can't find it and it doesn't tell me there is an error so could any of you guys help me?
This is the code:

```
if Function == '1':
    Amount = int (input ('How many Numbers do you need to use (9 numbers max and 2 numbers min):'))
    if Amount == '2':
        NumberOne = int (input ('Enter The First Number: '))
        print ''
        NumberTwo = int (input ('Enter The Second Number: '))
        Answer = NumberOne + NumberTwo
        def print_slow(str):
            for letter in str:
                sys.stdout.write(letter)
                sys.stdout.flush()
                time.sleep(0.4)

        print_slow(str (NumberOne) + ' + ' + str (NumberTwo) + ' = ' + str (Answer))

    elif Amount == '3':
        NumberOne = int (input ('Enter The First Number: '))
        print ''
        NumberTwo = int (input ('Enter The Second Number: '))
        print ''
        Numberthree = int (input ('Enter The Third Number: '))
        Answer = NumberOne + NumberTwo + Numberthree
        def print_slow(str):
            for letter in str:
                sys.stdout.write(letter)
                sys.stdout.flush()
                time.sleep(0.4)

        print_slow(str (NumberOne) + ' + ' + str (NumberTwo) + ' + ' + str (NumberThree) + ' = ' + str (Answer))
```

If you need all of the code then just ask I will be happy to post it....

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Which part is being skipped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing up `string` and `int` datatypes and therefore the comparisons are not working correctly.

Consider this line.

```
Amount = int (input ('How many Numbers do you need to use (9 numbers max and 2 numbers min):'))
```

You've type casted `Amount` as `int`, but in the next line,

```
if Amount == '2':
```

You're comparing the `int` valued `Amount` with `String '2'`. This is where your error lies. Change the above line to:

```
if Amount == 2:
```

Similarly, remove quotes from all the int-based comparisons and the code should work!

Comment: Thank you guys you have helped me i forgot that intergers don't need brackets.

Answer (score 1):

You've convert `amount` to an `int`, so when you try to compare`if Amount == '2':`, you should not add quotes around 2 which make it a `string` instead of a `int`, or it will return `False` and that's why code has been skipped.